# Use of store and select keywords in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

Im new to gremlin. i followed the document on [tinkerpop3](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/). But i couldn't understand the use of store and select keywords.. Can anyone explain it simply?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `store()` step collects objects that pass through the traversal as a side-effect of the traversal. For example let's say I have this traversal (using the modern toy graph packaged in TinkerPop):

```
gremlin> g.V().has("name","marko").store("markos").outE()
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
```

The traversal gets all the vertices named "marko" stores them in a list called "markos" and then traverse on their out edges with `outE()` and we get edges as the output. As an additional point, if we want to get that "markos" list out of our traversal we must `cap()` the traversal:

```
gremlin> g.V().has("name","marko").store("markos").outE().cap('markos')
==>[v[1]]
```

The `store()` step is a bit useless in this context, but imagine using it to tell Gremlin to collect things for you as he does his walk around the graph. Perhaps you could tell him to collect a bunch of edges for example:

```
gremlin> g.V().has("name","marko").outE().store("edges").inV().outE().store('edges').inV().cap('edges')
==>[e[9][1-created->3],e[7][1-knows->2],e[8][1-knows->4],e[10][4-created->5],e[11][4-created->3]]
```

You can also reference the list gathered by `store()` via via steps that allow access to side-effects. A common use case might be to ignore something already traversed:

```
gremlin> g.V().has("name","marko").store('marko').out().in()
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
==>v[1]
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().has("name","marko").store('marko').out().in().where(without('marko'))
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
```

It is important to recall that `store()` is lazy in its work. It collects as the traversal executes. If you need the opposite of that then you should go with `aggregate()` which is eager in its evaluation (it exhausts the traversal to the point that `aggregate()` is called).

The `select()` keyword lets you access previous parts of a traversal and to pick apart maps.  With respect to the former, you might need to access labelled steps:

```
gremlin> g.V().has("name","marko").as('a').outE().select('a')
==>v[1]
==>v[1]
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().has("name","marko").as('a').outE().inV().as('b').select('a','b')
==>[a:v[1],b:v[3]]
==>[a:v[1],b:v[2]]
==>[a:v[1],b:v[4]]
```

and as to the latter:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').valueMap().select('name')
==>[marko]
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').valueMap().select(values)
==>[[marko],[29]]
```

I'm not sure that there are specific use cases for when you need select as it is generic sort of step that has wide applicability.